# How to use a variable number of arguments in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding how to return information to the first function from the second when there are multiple arguments. Now I know the following code works.

```
function One() {
    var newVal = 0;
    newVal = Too(newVal);
    console.log(newVal);
}

function Too(arg) {
    ++arg;
    return arg;
}
```

But what if I try to complicate things by adding arguments and a setinterval.

```
function One() {
    var newVal = 0;
    var z = 3;
    var y = 3;
    var x = 1;
    newVal = Too(newVal);
    var StopAI2 = setInterval(function () {
        Too(x, y, z, newVal)
    }, 100);
}

function Too(Xarg, Yarg, Zarg, newValarg) {
    Xarg*Xarg;
    Yarg*Yarg;
    Zarg*Zarg;
    ++newValarg;
    return newValarg;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do with the newVal = line of code. I only want to return the newVal not x,y,z.

Comment: you can use `return ++arg;`.Save one line.

Comment: `newVal = Too(newVal);` won't even do what you are intending. You aren't passing X, Y, or Z at all. Why not do something like this: `newVal = Too(null, null, null, newVal);`

Comment: I have some other code that i'm using with three.js but it's really long so I just tried to simplify it here. Some one had answerd my question but it's gone now they advised I use arguments.length-1 or some thing like that.

Comment: more of less i'm trying to return info to the first function from the second but there are multiple arguments and I just want to return 1.

Comment: @mattedgod so I just have to replace the arguments that aren't being passed back with null?

Comment: @JohnBob Well you can, it really depends what you are doing with them in the function. In your example you aren't using them at all so you could replace with whatever you want.

Comment: I think the OP is not asking his real question clearly.  It seems like he wants to know how to operate on the 4th argument to a function when there won't always be 4 arguments.  Composing an answer...

Comment: I updated the example a bit. Sorry if this seems weird I'm just trying to understand the concept. I know if there is one argument then I have to do this newVal = Too(newVal);. But i'm not sure why that line has to be in there. also what dose that line have to be changed to if there are more than one argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think you're trying to ask:

> > How can I operate on the 4th argument to a function when only one argument is passed?

The answer to that question is this:

> > If you want to operate on the 4th argument of a function, at least 4 arguments must be passed to the function.

There are a few ways you can approach your problem differently.

### #1

If there's one argument that is always necessary, make sure it's the first argument:

```
 function Too(mandatoryArg, optionalArg1, optionalArg2) {
    alert(++mandatoryArg);
    if (optionalArg1) {
        alert(++optionalArg1);
    }
}
```

### #2

Pass placeholder values for all the undefined or unknown arguments.

You might use `null`, `undefined`, or `''`.

```
alert(Too(null, null, 4));

function Too(optArg1, optArg2, mandatoryArg) {
    alert(++mandatoryArg);
}
```

### #3

Make a decision based on the number of arguments:

```
function Too(optArg1, optArg2, optArg3) {
    var numArgs = arguments.length;
    if (numArgs === 1) {
        alert(++optArg1);
    }
    if (numArgs === 3) {
        alert(++optArg3);
    }
}
```

---

---

**EDIT**

> > "Will this update a variable in the first function?"

Let's use an actual example that demonstrates something:

```
function one() {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 25;
    var c = 50;
    var d = -1;

    d = two(a, b, c);

    alert("a: " + a);
    alert("b: " + b);
    alert("c: " + c);
    alert("d: " + d);
}

function two(a, b, c) {
    ++a;
    ++b;
    ++c;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return a;
    }
    if (arguments.length === 3) {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Invoking `one()` will cause the following alerts:

```
a: 0
b: 25
c: 50
d: 51
```

Only the value of `d` is modified in function *one()*.

That's because `d` is assigned the return value of *two()*.

The changes to `a`, `b`, and `c`, inside *two()* have no effect on the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` inside *one()*.

This would be the case even if the arguments for *two()* were named `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvnA4/) with the code above.

---

---

**EDIT #2**

Here is one way you could create functions that move a game object:

```
var FORWARD = 0;
var BACK = 1;
var LEFT = 2;
var RIGHT = 3;

// use an object with three values to represent a position
var pos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
};

pos = moveObject(pos, FORWARD);
printPosition(pos);

pos = moveObject(pos, LEFT);
printPosition(pos);

pos = moveObject(pos, FORWARD);
printPosition(pos);

pos = moveObject(pos, LEFT);
printPosition(pos);

// invoking moveObject() with one argument
// will move the object forward

pos = moveObject(pos);
printPosition(pos);

function moveObject(position, direction) {

    // assume FORWARD if no direction is specified
    if (typeof direction === 'undefined') {
        direction = FORWARD;
    }

    if (direction === FORWARD) {
        ++position.z;
    }
    if (direction === BACK) {
        --position.z;
    }
    if (direction === LEFT) {
        --position.x;
    }
    if (direction === RIGHT) {
        ++position.x;
    }

    return position;
}

function printPosition(pos) {
    alert(pos.x + ", " + pos.y + ", " + pos.z);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/Dnf5v/2/) that shows a working demo of another approach.

Comment: Will this update a variable in the first function? Sorry about not being able to clearly ask the question. Over all i'm just trying to figure out how to return info to the first function.

Comment: @JohnBob - I'll add a separate section to my answer to try to answer that question...

Comment: Ok I think i'm starting to understand. So no matter which parameter is returned the value will be appended to d?

Comment: @JohnBob - In this case, only the value of `d` will be modified in `one()`.  That is because it will be **assigned** the **return value** of `two()`.  The term "_appended_" does not apply here.  The term "_append_" is generally used with **strings** (_or maybe files_) and it means to "_add something to the end of something else_".

Answer (score 2):

There are two concepts that are at play here.

1 . Variable number of function parameters (or optional parameters).

If you are going to call the same function with different number of parameters (this will eventually lead to a world of headache), you need to determine (inside the function) how this function was called. You can use `arguments` object available inside each function:

```
function Too() {
  if (arguments.length == 4) {
    arguments[0]*arguments[0];
    arguments[1]*arguments[1];
    arguments[2]*arguments[2];
    return ++arguments[3];
  } else if (arguments.length == 1) {
    return ++arguments[0];
  } else {
    // you decide what to do here
  }
}
```

2 . Asynchronous code execution.

Realize that `Too` which is called when interval expires, executes well after `One` completes and returns. If you want `Too` to affect `newVal` variable, and somehow get at this new value afterwards, - make `newVal` variable global.

Comment: Yea that's what i'm trying to do. I'm going to explain further. Sorry if this dose not make any sense. I'm using three.js to make a simple game. I use function one to spawn an enemy then the set interval passes the info to the function that moves the enemy. My problem is I need to activate and deactivate sections of the function to move the enemy around. for example if it moves forward I need to deactivate the code that moves it backward. so they don't interfere with each other. If I use a global variable it works but then if more than one enemy is spawned they share moments.

Comment: I'm using if statements like if (spriteName.position.x > 100) { spriteName.position.x -= 10;} but at times the if statements conflict so i'm trying to use variable's to control the progression of what executes. like if (spriteName.position.x > 100 && newVal == 1) { spriteName.position.x -= 10;}. but it has to be a local variable or it will effect all the enemy's spawned. So i'm trying to pass it from the first function.

Comment: @JohnBob -  I'll add a simple code example to my answer to demonstrate an easy way to move game objects...